# Texture compression in OpenGL done by CPU or GPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am writing a simple C++/OpenGL program, which can load obejcts form .obj files. I use texture compression, but it is a bit slow. Is texture compression done by CPU or GPU?
If CPU I could do multithreading loading and compressing.

Here is code:

```
 if(format==GL_RGBA || format==GL_BGRA) 
        {
            if(transparency)    internalformat=GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT;    
            else internalformat=GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT;
        }

        if(format==GL_RGB || format==GL_BGR) internalformat=GL_COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT;
        if(format==GL_INTENSITY) internalformat=GL_COMPRESSED_INTENSITY;
.................
glGenTextures(1, &txtid[position]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, txtid[position]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,internalformat,txt->w,txt->h,0,format,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,txt->pixels);
```

Comment: It probably depends on the implementation. OpenGL just specifies that the implementation needs to compress the texture; it doesn't specify how.

Comment: It's implementation defined. But if you're using compressed textures you should compress them outside of your program and just load them with `glCompressedTexImage2D`